# Download a file from a redirected URL

Tags: php, download

I'm trying to download a video from a URL which is not the direct link, but a link which is forcing the download.  Now I want to download this to my server and convert it with ffmpeg. (I already know how to do this part)

So my question is, how to download a file via php from an *indirect* link?

Comment: You need to convert the `indirect` link to a `direct` link. Either by html scraping or other means. In any case, please post an example of the link at question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Do you mean the server redirects you?**

Downloading something in PHP is well done with CURL and is having the `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` option.

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "www.mywebdownloadurl.com/dl?id=someId");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true); // Videos are needed to transfered in binary
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); // That's the clue! 
$result = curl_exec($ch); // $result will have your video.
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Comment: This is true. Then only html/js-fetching and automation is the thing to do.

Comment: It's a bit weird, because now i think it's crashing or at least not loading the script complete. Is there a way to catch errors in php so i can look at which part it is failing?

Comment: `ERROR_REPORTING(E_ALL);`

Comment: Am i wrong or how should i write this to a temporary file? I'm currently using tmpfile() and file_put_contents which is giving me no error but the php script only runs until this point. All content after this isn't displayed. Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Is the tempfile filled?

Comment: No i don't think so. I'm declaring it like $file = tmpfile(); and later on "filling" it with file_put_contents($file, $result);

Comment: Ok after a few moments of frustration, ive got a solution :) I don't know the exactly reason but after i manually wget the download link it said that the url is too long. Right now i'm using the bitly api, short the url and using your cUrl code for the redirection. Thanks a Lot!